# Qml - How to stop a rectangle dragging outside it's parent

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml

I am using qml to create a resizable rectangle that can be dragged inside it's parent pane, but cannot be dragged outside (Fig. 1). When I resize it e.g. using the top left handle, it works great and can't be resized outside it's parent (Fig. 2). But when I drag the entire rectangle, it can be dragged outside its parent (Fig. 3). My code attempts to use the same logic for both, i.e. once the rectangle's left side reaches it's parent's left side, it cancels the drag. Works fine for resizing, but doesn't when I drag the rectangle. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Fig 1] [image: Fig 2] [image: Fig3]

```
Pane {
            id: compPane
            implicitHeight: imageListModel.reqViewHeight
            implicitWidth: imageListModel.reqViewWidth
            leftPadding: 0
            topPadding: 0
            clip: true

            background: Rectangle{
                id: backgroundRect
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "gray"
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 6
            }

            // Resizable rectangle that can be dragged
            Rectangle {
                id: indRect
                x:parent.width / 4
                y: parent.height / 4
                width: parent.width / 2
                height: parent.width / 2
                border {
                    width: 2
                    color: "steelblue"
                }
                color: "#354682B4"

                MouseArea {
                    id: indImagesDragArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 8
                    drag.target: parent

                    onPositionChanged: {
                        if (drag.active){
                            if (indRect.x <= 0 + backgroundRect.border.width)
                                Drag.cancel()
                            if (indRect.x + indRect.width >= (compPane.width - backgroundRect.border.width) )
                                Drag.cancel()
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Top Left handle - works well
                Rectangle {
                    width: 15
                    height: 15
                    color: "steelblue"
                    anchors.verticalCenter:parent.top
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.left
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        cursorShape: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAndYAxis }
                        onPositionChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){
                                //var delta = Math.max(mouseX, mouseY)
                                var newWidth = indRect.width - mouseX
                                var newHeight = indRect.height - mouseY;

                                if (newWidth < width || newHeight < height)
                                    return

                                if (indRect.x <= 0 + backgroundRect.border.width && mouseX < 0){
                                    Drag.cancel()
                                    indRect.x =  0 + backgroundRect.border.width
                                }
                                else {
                                    indRect.width = newWidth
                                    indRect.x = indRect.x + mouseX
                                }

                                if (indRect.y <= 0 + backgroundRect.border.width && mouseY < 0){
                                    Drag.cancel()
                                    indRect.y = 0 + backgroundRect.border.width
                                }
                                else{
                                    indRect.height = newHeight
                                    indRect.y = indRect.y + mouseY
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Drag.cancel()` is actually intended for use when implementing drag and drop types of interactions. In this case, the calls to it are doing nothing because you are never actually starting one of those sequences. Your upper left handle example works fine if you comment out the calls to `Drag.cancel()`.

Why your upper left example is working is because you are limiting the x and y on position updates to clip them to the scene via explicit updates of `indRect.x` and `indRect.y`. You just need to implement the same technique for the main drag scenario.

For instance:

```
onPositionChanged: {
    if (drag.active){
        if (indRect.x <= 0 + backgroundRect.border.width)
            indRect.x =  0 + backgroundRect.border.width;
        if (indRect.x + indRect.width >= (compPane.width - backgroundRect.border.width) )
            indRect.x = compPane.width - backgroundRect.border.width - indRect.width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Perfect. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the property of drag.minimum and drag.maximum.
See the documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#drag.threshold-prop